# How do I tell Camunda (in Modeller) v7.15.0 that Java Delegates are remotely deployed?

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I have Camunda 7.15.0 deployed in GCP Cloud Run. I have a Java 11 application through which I wish to access the Camunda RuntimeService in order to start a process instance, but this requires some community extension so I went with Camunda REST API. Now I want to add Java Delegates coded in the above Java application, how do I tell Camunda (Modeller) that Java Delegates are remote?

Answer (score 1):

The Java Delegates are only working if you embed Camunda in your application as library.

In your case you need to work with the External Task pattern.

Here is a Blog, that explains this Pattern: https://medium.com/@dashedsouvik/camunda-external-task-pattern-fd84a29d9d3e

Answer (score 0):

(I assume you are asking about Camunda 7.x)

If the code is supposed to run in a different JVM, change the model to use implementation type "external". Then change the JavaDelegate. You do not need to implement this interface anymore. Instead, for Camunda 7 use one of the client libraries:
https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/awesome-camunda-external-clients

The libraries take care of the remote communication to the engine. You only need to change the delegate code to be wrapped similar to this: https://github.com/rob2universe/c7-rest-task-worker/blob/main/src/main/java/com/camunda/example/worker/RESTWorker.java

Also see:

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/user-guide/ext-client/

https://blog.bernd-ruecker.com/moving-from-embedded-to-remote-workflow-engines-8472992cc371